# Navigating through a string and updating the value of string while navigating

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I have got the following code in Python (in PyCharm Community Edition):

```
def defer_tags(sentence):

    for letter in sentence:
        print(letter)
        if letter == '<':
            end_tag = sentence.find('>')
            sentence = sentence[end_tag+1:]
            print(sentence)

defer_tags("<h1>Hello")
```

It produced the following output:

```
current letter =  <
new_sentence =  Hello
current letter =  h
current letter =  1
current letter =  >
current letter =  H
current letter =  e
current letter =  l
current letter =  l
current letter =  o
```

Why does loop (`letter`) navigate through the entire string (`sentence`) even though the value of `sentence` has changed inside the loop ?

I am printing out the value of `sentence` after the change but it is not getting reflected in the loop iterations.

Comment: Strings are immutable in python. You create a new string at each loop run, but the loop itself runs on the initial string.

Comment: Are you trying to catch the words between tags?

Comment: Thanks spectras. I guess I will have to make a new variable to store the value of mutated string.

Comment: @Nf4r Yupp. Thats what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

To be explicit, try using beautiful soup following way:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<h1>Hello<h1>')
>>> soup.text
u'Hello'
```

Answer (score -1):

Better way to catch phrases from tags is just simple to use re.

```
import re
def defer_tags(sentence):
    return re.findall(r'>(.+)<', sentence)

defer_tags('<h1>Hello<h1>')
> ['Hello']
defer_tags('<h1>Hello</h1><h2>Ahoy</h2>')
> ['Hello', 'Ahoy']
```

This will work if the tags are full. Ie `<h2>Hello</h2>` of `<h1>Ahoy</h1> <h2>XX</h2>` etc.

Comment: I am getting the following output for both the cases:

Comment: ['Hello<h1>']
['Hello</h1><h2>Ahoy</h2>']

Comment: You don't parse HTML with regular expressions. [Ever.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). And as a counter-example to your idea: `<h1 id=">I_am_a_valid_id<">Hello</h1>`